# Is exFAT filesystem a good choice for USB3 HDD connected to a home NAS server on Raspbian?

Tags: filesystems, network-attached-storage, usb, exfat

I have a home NAS on Raspberry PI4 with a USB3 HDD connected. I have a variety of devices with different OSs (Linux, Win and Mac), and I'd like to be able to access that HDD from any of those with a direct USB connection if need be. Which FS should I use? I'm thinking about exFAT. Is there any reason why exFAT should not be used in a home NAS?

**Update:** Apparently, OpenMdeiaVault that I'm using does not support exFAT, so I'm going with Ext4 and look for Win 10 / Mac drivers for it.

Comment: fat uses only private user, yo believe that your question is not Business related and should be moved to superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really suggest you to use an ext3/4 filesystem. exFAT should be used only when sharing data with a Windows system where no ext3/4 drives can be installed, or it is not expected to be installed (eg: sdcards used by digital camera, which can be plugged in any Windows PC).

Comment: Yes, after reading more forums, I decided to go with Ext4 and install drivers on my Mac/Win systems.

Comment: If you share in the network, you need the OS to support CIFS/SMB. Windows and Mac support natively CIFS (aka Windows file sharing, aka SMB).

Answer (score 1):

ExFAT is not a great file system but it will work for you in this situation. You didn't mention what OS you are running on your Pi but you will need extra software for using exfat:

```sh
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

After this, you can mount your drive with this command:

```
# create folder to mount to
sudo mkdir /mnt/MyHDD

# output your devices
sudo fdisk -l

# where sdb1 is the partition of your hdd from the previous command
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/MyHDD
```